# set position of svg path in world map svg

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, jquery-svg

I have one world map with the SVG format and I am trying to set the position of the selected country in the center of the screen using jquery

I am using this SVG map in my project

[SVG Map image link](https://simplemaps.com/static/demos/resources/svg-library/svgs/world.svg)

```js
$('#hidemap').on('click', function() {
    $('path').attr('display','none');    
    var c = cnt.options[cnt.selectedIndex].value;
    $('#'+c).attr('display','block');
    $('#'+c).css("transform-origin", "center center 0");
    $('#'+c).css("transform-box"," fill-box");
    $('#'+c).css("stroke", "black");
    $('#'+c).css("transform"," scale(2)");
    var d = document.getElementById(c).getAttribute("d").replace(/\r?\n|\r/g, "");
    console.log(d);
    var height = parseInt($('#'+c)[0].getBoundingClientRect().height);
    var width = parseInt($('#'+c)[0].getBoundingClientRect().width);    
    var transform_Y = (height/2) - ($(window).height() / 2);
    var transform_X = (width/2) - ($(window).width() / 2);    
    d_array = d.split(",");
    d_array[0].slice(0);
    var $box = $("#svg_div");    
    width_array =d_array[0].split(" ");
    height_array =d_array[1].split(" ");
    width_array[1] = 1000;
    height_array[0] = 500;
    console.log(width_array);
    d_array[0] = width_array[0]+" "+width_array[1];
    d_array[1] = height_array[0]+" "+height_array[1];
    var string_array = d_array.toString();
    console.log(string_array);
    document.getElementById(c).setAttribute("d",string_array );   
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

above is my code so now i want to draw selected country map in center of scree if selected map is on left side or right side

please help me out for this issue

Comment: `"message": "ReferenceError: $ is not defined"` means you are not loading jQuery. Is that your problem?

Comment: i have added jquery please check it now

Comment: where is the id tag that initiates the jquery code who's id is hidemap

Comment: Please include a working [mcve] in your question.  Your existing code example is incomplete. For example `cnt` is not defined.  Also, it is not clear whether you want to move the whole map (so the country is centred), or if you just want to move the country path individually.